# -webkit-user-select:none and -ms-user-select:none copying the content

Tags: javascript, css, copy-paste

I am trying to disable selection of some `<td>`s of table having specific class. In the CSS file for that class I added

```
-webkit-user-select: none;  
-ms-user-select: none;
```

But neither of them seems to work. Only visually it appears that those `<td>`s are not getting selected. But if I copy and paste the data, content from those cells is also getting copied. Browser version are - 
IE 11 and Chrome 43.0.2357.132 m

Adding `-moz-user-select: none;` works perfect for Firefox. Any idea why it is not working for rest two browsers?

Comment: [`user-select` is not a standard and cannot be relied upon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select): "This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future."

Comment: Why do you want to disable text selection? To stop visitors from copying copyright-protected content? Or to stop automated scraping of your content?

Comment: Its my application's requirement. I am building a CodeSearch application similar to [gitHub](https://github.com/anthonybaker/JsonAPIClient/blob/master/JsonApiClient/Program.cs) Here, if you try copying in the source code area, line numbers are not copied, only source code is copied. I want to achieve similar in my application.

Comment: @Saurabh `user-select` isn't described in the spec, therefore you should not use it and complaint that it doesn't work. You can try to "disable" selecting and copying with JavaScript, but the browser can always override your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure the line numbers aren't being copied, you can use a standard `<ol>` tag:

```
<ol>
    <li>Can't select line number</li>
</ol>
```

To style it, create [a counter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters) along with [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Abefore) to make it not selectable. You can use any element (not only `<ol>`) with this method.

Demo with additional styling: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/ae2fggL5/

[image]
(Chrome) Line numbers appear that they are selected, but you can't actually copy them or select them individually.

[image]
(Firefox) Line numbers can't be selected in Firefox.

Comment: I guess you mean "aren't being copied" ?